# R: Title for a complete plot area (when there are several plots with mfrow...)

Tags: r, plot

I'm generating some large images with several plots on it with:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,3))
```

The title parameter sets only a title for the current plot (which I need as well):

```
par(main="Title")
```

But how can I set a title for the whole plot area?

Comment: One way is to use `mtext`: mtext("Big title", side = 3, line = -1, outer = TRUE)

Comment: The [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/) website is a great resource if you're new to R. Combining plots is discussed [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html).